# Why POST requests are turned into GET in django with wsgi?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I have a Django 1.9.4 site.

In localhost, I could easily submit the form and have the results that I want.

But when it's on the server, the POST request turns into a GET request.

On local, I use `python manage.py runserver` but on server I use Apache2, WSGI

Local:

- django 1.9.4
- python 2.7.10
- Ubuntu 15.10

Server:

- same django
- python 2.7.6
- Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- Ubuntu 14.04

Server `example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    Alias /static /var/www/example.com/static
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Alias /media /var/www/example.com/media
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/wh>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess webhistory python-path=/var/www/example.com:/var/www/example.com/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup webhistory
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/wh/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log 
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined
    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/example.com/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/example.com/favicon.ico
</VirtualHost>
```

And the `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "wh.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And the craziest part is that even my `admin` app doesn't work properly.
All the POST submitted forms turn into GET ones.

Here is the error:

`request    <WSGIRequest: GET '/someurl/'>`

What's the problem?

Is it related to `APPEND_SLASH = True`?

And here's what's realley bothering me... The form submission worked once! why isn't it working again?

Comment: Do you have an example post request where this happens?

Comment: [Buy page](http://webhistory.ir/buy/)